# Impl Trait return type hidden lifetimes

Tags: rust, lifetime, associated-types

I want to return an iterator over values of a type that implements a non-static trait with an associated type as such:

```rust
trait Test<'a> {
    type B;
}

struct A<'a, T: Test<'a>> {
    map: Vec<(T::B, T)>,
    _phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a T>
}

impl<'a, T: Test<'a>> A<'a, T> {
    pub fn iter<'b>(&'b self) -> impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = &'b T> + 'b
    {
        self.map.iter().map(|(_,value)| value)
    }
}
```

(The lifetimes are as explicit as possible to make sure this wasn't an error of the compiler assuming the wrong lifetimes)

This gives the following error however:

```rust
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Trait` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:11:34
   |
11 |     pub fn iter<'b>(&'b self) -> impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = &'b T> + 'b
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: hidden type `std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'b, (<T as Test<'a>>::B, T)>, [closure@src/lib.rs:13:29: 13:46]>` captures the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 10:6
  --> src/lib.rs:10:6
   |
10 | impl<'a, T: Test<'a>> A<'a, T> {
   |      ^^
```

Because the type actually returned need the lifetime `'a` to be able to determine `T::B` (although, I'm not sure why, as it could use `T::B` instead of `<T as Test<'a>>::B`).

I can fix it by instead naming the type B as such:

```rust
trait Test<'a> {
    type B;
}

struct A<'a, U, T: Test<'a, B = U>> {
    map: Vec<(U, T)>,
    _phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a T>
}

impl<'a, U, T: Test<'a, B = U>> A<'a, U, T> {
    pub fn iter<'b>(&'b self) -> impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = &'b T> + 'b
    {
        self.map.iter().map(|(_,value)| value)
    }
}
```

This solves it because the hidden type is now `std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'b, (U, T)>, [closure@src/lib.rs:13:29: 13:46]>`, where `<T as Test<'a>>::B` was replaced by `U`, thus hiding the lifetime `'a`.

However this introduces a new type to the signature of `A`, which propagates downstream to anything that might use `A`, which would be a major breaking change.

Is there any solution to this problem that would not change the signature of `A`?

Edit: I realize I may use the type itself to fix the problem instead of `impl Trait`, but the point of `impl Trait` is to hide the type used in case I ever change the underlying representation of `A`.

Comment: Wow, that is an astonishingly helpful error message.

Comment: *Because the type actually returned need the lifetime `'a` to be able to determine `T::B` (although, I'm not sure why, as it could use `T::B` instead of `<T as Test<'a>>::B`)* But `B` *itself* could contain the lifetime `'a`, e.g. `type B = &'a i32` or something like that, and the compiler would still have to prove the closure outlives it.

Comment: @trentcl Yes, but both in this case and in my particular case, B is a `'static` type, in my case usually even just `usize` or sometimes `&'static str`, so it would not use the `'a` lifetime.

Comment: [Here's my answer to the other question applied to yours.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0304b7a772a20e403f4305f972c9c870) You were pretty close, you just didn't have to also put `U` on `A` as well. Another option is [to put `U: 'a` on the `impl` instead of `U: 'b` on the `fn`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba40e6d8ca5b14afeb8a6936b3da8f92); this is more restrictive on what `U` can be.

Comment: @trentcl Only adding a generic `U`on the impl / fn seems to work really well! If you'd like to post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @trentcl Also, although this does solve the original question, do you have any idea why the compiler attempts to use `<T as Test<'a>>::B` instead of just `T::B`, which would no longer have the `'a` lifetime? If I tried to [return an iterator over `T::B` it fails because it seems to say that T is actually `Test<'static>` instead of `Test<'a>`? I don't fully understand the problem with it, and I think it might relate to what's happening in this case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=02359261174f24d8428f29d587ddb4b7)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206537/discussion-between-trentcl-and-filipe-rodrigues).